# reorder barchart by sum of bar segments with ggplot/plyr

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr, geom-bar

I need the 11 bars in the following stacked barplot to be *reordered by the sum of the first two segments* of each bar, i.e. sorted by the (red+green) segments in the plot.

```
> dput(q1m.bl)
structure(list(ItemA = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("sehr wichtig", "wichtig", "unwichtig", 
"keine Angabe"), class = "factor"), ItemQ = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), .Label = c("PUSHERS_AA", 
"PUSHERS_COM", "PUSHERS_BED", "PUSHERS_SEC", "PUSHERS_STAB", 
"PUSHERS_COST", "PUSHERS_INNO", "PUSHERS_VAL", "PUSHERS_INDEP", 
"PUSHERS_STDS", "PUSHERS_SRC"), class = "factor"), Counts = c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
6L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L), blpos = c(0.111111111111111, 
0.444444444444444, 0.888888888888889, 1, 0.333333333333333,   0.666666666666667, 
0.888888888888889, 1, 0.444444444444444, 0.666666666666667, 0.888888888888889, 
1, 0.333333333333333, 0.888888888888889, 1, 0.111111111111111, 
0.222222222222222, 0.888888888888889, 1, 0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 
0.888888888888889, 1, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.888888888888889, 
1, 0.222222222222222, 0.888888888888889, 1, 0.222222222222222, 
0.666666666666667, 0.888888888888889, 1, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.888888888888889, 1, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.888888888888889, 
1)), .Names = c("ItemA", "ItemQ", "Counts", "blpos"), row.names = c(NA, 
-42L), class = "data.frame")
```

The plot ...

```
ggplot(q1m.bl, aes(x = ItemQ, y = Counts, fill = ItemA)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="fill") + 
geom_text(aes(y = blpos, label = Counts), hjust = 1) +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust = 0), text = element_text(size=10)) +
coord_flip()
```

Ugh, not enough rep points to embed images. Sorry for the inconvenience. Plot is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/am0Ud.png

I played around with arrange() and after checking the data frame itself, I thought the following sorting should do the trick. (Note: blpos means "bar label position" and are the positions of the various numbers in the plot.) But plotting this "sorted" data frame leads to the identical plot as above. I do not understand which information to change to change the plotting order of the ItemQ column.

```
q1m.bl.s <- arrange(q1m.bl, ItemA, desc(blpos))
ggplot(q1m.bl.s, ....
```

What's the best approach anyway? Should I *manipulate the df* (using ddply/arrange/reorder/etc.) prior to plotting? Because I tend to think this is a presentation issue and should be done *inside* ggplot. Does it even matter? The "ggplot ordered barchart" questions I found on SO seem to use both approaches; yet none I found was referring to stacked bar *segments* and using factor data... hence this new question.

Thank you very much for enlightening me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about re-ordering the factor levels of the `ItemQ` variable.

```
d <- subset(q1m.bl, ItemA %in% c("sehr wichtig", "wichtig"))
totals <- aggregate(d$Counts, list(ItemQ = d$ItemQ), sum)
ItemQ.order <- as.character(totals[order(-totals$x), ]$ItemQ)
q1m.bl$ItemQ <- factor(q1m.bl$ItemQ, levels = ItemQ.order)
```

Then you should be able to run the code exactly as you provided it and it will produce this:[image]

EDIT (digisus): konvas, I am just re-adding your first answer showing the use of ddply because even I do not feel comfortable with it/do not fully get it, I am sure others can benefit from it. :-) So, with your permission I repost it here:

```
library(plyr)
ItemQ.order <- q1m.bl %>%
  group_by(ItemQ) %>% 
  filter(ItemA %in% c("sehr wichtig", "wichtig")) %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(Counts)) %>%
  arrange(-total) %>% 
  select(ItemQ) %>%
  unlist %>%
  as.character

q1m.bl$ItemQ <- factor(q1m.bl$ItemQ, levels = ItemQ.order)
```

Comment: _@konvas_, thank you for the fast response! Unfortunately, I get **Error: could not find function "%>%"** -- I am in fact not familiar with this "%>%" function/notation. (likewise with %in% though I can guesstimate what it might mean.) If you could elaborate a bit on this, that would help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: This operator is part of the dplyr/magrittr packages and is used for an easy syntactical way of chaining commands. For example, you have a function `f` of two variables. Then instead of writing `f(a,b)` you can write `a %>% f(b)`. This becomes useful when you have more functions eg `g(f(a, b), c)` becomes `a %>% f(b) %>% g(c)` and so on... See the helpfiles for more info. I just used this to obtain the elements of `ItemQ` in the desired order. If you are more familiar with other methods (e.g. `aggregate` etc) feel free to use those..

Comment: Thanks @konvas. I will install these packages and check them out. I just wonder ... why seemingly easy tasks regularly 'explode' to be so complicated in R. :-/

Comment: Followup. I am stuck already at install: ERROR: dependency ‘lazyeval’ is not available for package ‘dplyr’. Thanks for your efforts konvas, but unless someone may point me to an easier solution, I have to give up. In fact, due to time constraints, I will have to revert to (gasp) a spreadsheet application. I spent >1 week to only get 5 barchart plots and I did not even achieve this. Sorry to dump this here, it is just very frustrating. Thank you neverthelesse for taking the time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)

fac_ord <- function(seed){
  set.seed(seed)
  return(sample(letters[1:4]))
}

# this seed simulates arbitrary sortings
seed <- 2
fac_ord(seed)

val = c(1,2,3,4,2,2,2,2)
fac = factor(c("a","b","c","d","a","b","c","d"), 
             levels=fac_ord(seed), 
             labels=fac_ord(seed), 
             ordered=FALSE)
dif = c(rep("x",4),rep("y",4))

df  = data.frame(val = val, fac = fac)

ggplot(df, aes(x=fac, y=val, fill=dif)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  labs(title = sprintf("seed = %d / %s", seed, paste(fac_ord(seed),collapse=",")))
```

As the example shows - ggplot will use same ordering for `fac` in the plot as the internal order of `fac`. So to influence the plotted order you have to write a function which returns the intended order - in dependence on whatever facts and values - and use this to create the factor `fac` - and then use this propperly-ordered factor for the plotting.

[image]

[image]

The intended result can also be reached by application of [reorder()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/reorder.factor.html) for reordering the levels of the factor.

Comment: Thank you for making the effort to explain the core logic. I will mull over this some more... I feel it also helps to understand @konvas answers better. Thank you!